# How do you refer to or reuse one alias from another using deps.edn?

Tags: clojure, alias, deps-edn

It seems as though it's not possible to reuse one deps.edn alias from another, but I'd love to be proven wrong about this.

For example, say you have a `:dev` alias with some `:extra-deps`, `:extra-paths`, etc, and then a handful of dev-related aliases which can only be run with the stuff in `:dev`. You can obviously just run with `-A:dev:other-alias` (or `-M`, `-X`, etc), but it seems like there should be a way to just say that `:other-alias` depends on `:dev` so that explicitly adding it is not necessary.

I have tried adding `:main-opts ["-A:dev"]`, but this doesn't work (you get a `java.io.FileNotFoundException: -A:dev (No such file or directory)`, suggesting that it thinks this is the name of a `clj` file you're trying to run.

Is there a way to do this, or are we stuck either duplicating content or requiring users to explicitly add the reused (e.g. `:dev`) alias?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible right now. You can vote for this feature request at https://ask.clojure.org/index.php/10564/specify-an-alias-that-is-a-set-of-other-aliases